# How to compare 2 groups to show significant differences?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, inference, group-differences, control-group

I am conducting an experimental study. I have 2 groups: The first group contains 3 healthy persons and the other one contains 3 patients (sick people). For each person of the study, we collect several cells, from which we extract 3 features.

The goal is to show significant differences between the 2 groups. In other way, we have:

[image: image of data table]

x are numerical values

Which test is the more suitable to show significant difference between the patient and the healthy group?

I saw several tests like Hotelling, ANOVA ..., but in those tests the mean of each group is computed on all cells of all the people of a group without making a difference between the person within the group. Is it possible to include person variablity in such test? Is 2-way ANOVA a solution to take into consideration the people in the comparison? The two independant variables (factors) are thus the identity of the person and its situation (Healthy or patient)?